# How can I use vim as an email editor in Evolution Mail?

Tags: ubuntu, vim, evolution

I currently run an Ubuntu Natty desktop and I have to use Evolution mail to communicate with my offices Exchange server and deal with meeting requests and calendaring. Claws-Mail won't work as it does not support [SMTP GSSAPI or NTLM authentication](http://www.claws-mail.org/faq/index.php/Connecting_to_MS_Exchange).

How can use vim as my editor when composing an email in Evolution mail? Is it even possible?

I have scoured the web and I have not been able to find any up to date information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were running under Win32, I would recommend [external.exe](http://bur.st/~benc/site/?external): with that tool, you could use your favourite editor for all text editing tasks.

And hey: as I see, they do also have a port for Linux: http://bur.st/~benc/site/index.cgi?external-edit